# Change Compiler Options in Intel PIN

Tags: compilation, shared-libraries, compiler-warnings, intel-pin

How can I change g++ options while compiling a Pin tool? For example, is it possible to prevent warnings from being treated as errors or is it possible to link the tool with an external library such as bfd?

Comment: Linking to an external library: https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/pinheads/conversations/topics/12356

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking Pin to precompiled libraries is discouraged. Pin uses a different libc and linking will either fail or cause issues while running. If you wish to use an external library either compile it against pin's runtime or use it in a separate process.

To build specific files in a nonstandard way, add a rule to the `Build rules` section of the relevant makefile.

In general it is a bad idea to modify pin's default flags. They all serve a purpose.

Comment: Look at a ``makefile.rules`` file in the pin kit to see how special rules look like

Comment: Should I delete the matching target in $(TOOLS_ROOT)/Config/makefile.default.rules and add my own rule in the makefile.rules file of my tool directory?

Comment: No, your own targets will overwrite the default targets. Don't delete the default targets because this will make all non-custom build rules fail.

Comment: Thanks! This link is also helpful: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/index.html#MAKEFILES

Answer (score 0):

So gcc 7 added in some additional warnings which broke a pin-tool of mine. So I wanted to remove the `-Werror` command line argument. This shouldn't affect the end binary, so it should be perfectly safe.

You can simply remove it from the list of pin specified arguments with filter-out.

This is the entire contents of the "build rules" part of my makefile.rules

```
MY_CXX_FLAGS:=$(filter-out -Werror, $(TOOL_CXXFLAGS))

$(OBJDIR)generate_loop_info$(OBJ_SUFFIX): generate_loop_info.cpp
    $(CXX) $(MY_CXX_FLAGS) -D OUTPUT_FILE $(COMP_OBJ)$@ $<

$(OBJDIR)generate_loop_info$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX): $(OBJDIR)generate_loop_info$(OBJ_SUFFIX)
    $(LINKER)  $(TOOL_LDFLAGS) $(LINK_EXE)$@ $< $(TOOL_LPATHS) $(TOOL_LIBS)
```